# Error message "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" with nan in the data

Tags: python, pandas

My task is to convert columns `dcpower` and `acpower` (whichever is applicable) from kW to watt if their current units is kW. My data contain `nan` but I don't want to remove them. Below is my script.

```
if powerunit == 'watt':
    pass

if powerunit == 'kW':
    if 'dcpower' in df.columns:
        df['dcpower'] = (df['dcpower'] * 1000.0).copy()
    else:
        pass
    if 'acpower' in df.columns:
        df['acpower'] = (df['acpower'] * 1000.0).copy()
    else:
        pass
```

The script works, but it returns `SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`... 
`# This is added back by InteractiveShellApp.init_path()`

By adding `df.loc['power']` or `df.iloc['power']` and `.copy()` at the end, it does not work in my machine.

```
df["dcpower"] = (df.iloc["dcpower"] * 1000.0, "dcpower").copy()
```

returns `Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key`.

Sample data

```
Iac power   wind    Tamb    RH  ghi dhi WDir    rain
Timestamp                                       
2019-04-02 17:35:00 3.62    0.84    nan 27.82   nan 194.10  33.56   28.52   nan
2019-04-02 17:40:00 3.04    0.69    nan 27.59   nan 152.22  35.96   28.58   nan
2019-04-02 17:45:00 2.51    0.54    nan 27.52   nan 112.86  34.04   28.78   nan
2019-04-02 17:50:00 2.11    0.40    nan 27.43   nan nan 34.51   29.00   nan
2019-04-02 17:55:00 1.86    nan nan 27.32   nan nan 30.63   29.10   nan
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
Python: 3.7.4
JupyterLab: 1.1.4

Comment: Your code is not simplify? Is possible show all code?

Comment: try replacing nan with 0. It might be causing an error

Comment: @ShahirAnsari - No, you are wrong.

Comment: @jezrael. The code is complete. I only changed the name of my dataframe to ```df```.

Comment: ok, so not understand. There is missing how is created DataFrame. Also I think problem is in some code what you think cannot influencing your error, but unfortunately it cause error. Because problem of this error it show for any row and in 99% in another row where is reason of error

Comment: @jezrael. The data is .csv from field measurements. Anyway, thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @k.ko3n - hmmm, can you show me all your code? Be free change file name if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For me your code working very nice with no error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'dcpower':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'acpower':[7,8,9,4,2,3],

})

powerunit = 'kW'
if powerunit == 'kW':
    if 'dcpower' in df.columns:
        df['dcpower'] = (df['dcpower'] * 1000.0)
    else:
        pass
    if 'acpower' in df.columns:
        df['acpower'] = (df['acpower'] * 1000.0)
    else:
        pass

print (df)
   dcpower  acpower
0   4000.0   7000.0
1   5000.0   8000.0
2   4000.0   9000.0
3   5000.0   4000.0
4   5000.0   2000.0
5   4000.0   3000.0
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say it work but return a warning. The post has been editied

Comment: Code what you post working nice, it is all your code? Or some rows of code missing?

Comment: It works now after duplicating the whole ```df``` using ```df2 = df.copy()``` and then apply the script to ```df2``` instead of ```df```. However, I am still curious if it could be resolved without creating a duplicate of the df.

Comment: @k.ko3n - Hard question, because yourcompletely  code missing, so impossible find answer.